# How To Proceed File #2 Only When Accessed By File #1? I'm Using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have 2 files :

```
// test-redirect1.php
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['ctrl_access'] = '81938193813819381';
  // then some codes here...
?>
```

and this file :

```
// test-redirect2.php
<?php
  session_start();
  if ($_SESSION['ctrl_access'] != '81938193813819381') {
    header( 'Location : goto-hell.php' );
  }
  // then some codes here...
?>
```

I want to have `test-redirect2.php` only proceed when the referrer file is `test-redirect1.php`.

I tried to use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` in `test-redirect2.php` but it doesn't show up if `test-redirect1.php` use `header( 'Location : some-file' );` as redirect.

also, I don't want to show the `ctrl_access` variable to user. That's why I don't want to use POST / GET method.

so, I decided to go with `$_SESSION`...

but, the problem with the `$_SESSION` is, once I open `test-redirect1.php` on my browser, that variable is created then I can open `test-redirect2.php` and passing `if` condition.

how to have `test-redirect2.php` only proceed when the referrer file is `test-redirect1.php`?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "http referer" variable is sent by the browser.  It is not a good security method for that reason, as it can be easily spoofed, however, you already answered your question as to how it is sent reliably.  It is sent when you move from one page to another via a user clicking on a link.

You could probably trigger this behavior with javascript in a variety of ways such as:

```
document.getElementById('some_link_id').click();
```

The entire idea is bad.  Adult sites were infamous for using this technique for security, and were easily exploited using browser plugins that let you set HTTP headers.

The session method you were using is far better.

Comment: hi bro, thanks for your answer. but the main problem with $_SESSION is once I open test-redirect1.php on my browser, that variable is created then I can open test-redirect2.php and passing if condition. any idea how to solve this with $_SESSION?

Comment: In test-redirect2.php, just remove the session variable.  For example, $_SESSION['ctrl_access'] = ''; or unset($_SESSION['ctrl_access']);  Put this right before the header call and right after the if statement.  Also you should have an exit statement after it, inside the header call.  Header calls are also executed by the browser so people may choose to not honor them with browser plugins, just to see what your site might do.